# While calling store.commit recived Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit') why?

Tags: typescript, vuex, vuejs3

I want make a commit or dispatch form composition api aspecially onMounted
but it returns

- Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commit')

this is what i did up tu now. Please help I realy don't know what to do

store:

```
export default store(function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = createStore<StateInterface>({

 state: {
      example:'example'//
 }

 mutations:{
      letPrintSth(){
        console.log("hello i'm in vuex commit");
      }
    },

 actions:{
      letPrintFirst(){
        console.log("hello i'm in vuex dispatch");
      }
    },


    strict: !!process.env.DEBUGGING,
  });

  return Store;
});
```

component:

```
import { defineComponent, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default defineComponent({
name: 'dummyComponent'

setup(){

const store = useStore()

//me. methodes
function helloFunction(){
    store.commit('letPrintSth')
}

//me. hooks
onMounted(()=>{
    store.dispatch('letPrintFirst')
})

return{
helloFunction, //me. calling function by btn for example
}
})
```

Comment: did you try by putting it into the return statement `return{ helloFunction, store }
`

Comment: Yes, still same error

Comment: Ok! i have it. So first Ifaruki was right store has to be return and next be carefult with paths in my case import should look like import { useStore } from 'src/store'; yup congrats to me 6 hours lost.